# Solving a limit with radicals without l'Hopital

Tags: limits, radicals

I've been trying to solve this particular expression, rationalizing the numerator, and the denominator by conjugate multiplying, squaring, multiplying/dividing with x/x, nothing seems to work, I would appreciate any input.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}-1}$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305497/calculating-the-following-limit-lim-x-to-0-frac-sqrtx21-sqrtx1?rq=1

Comment: Multiply this by $$\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+1}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}$$ and use the identity $$(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})=a-b$$Alternatively, consult any of the myriad of questions on the site using this multiplication by the conjugate quantity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}-1}
&=
\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}-1}
\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}
\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+1}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\[6px]
&=
\frac{(1+x)-(1+x^2)}{(1+x)-1}
\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+1}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\[6px]
&=
\frac{x(1-x)}{x}
\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+1}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\[6px]
\end{align}
Now it's easy, isn't it?