# In the principal value of $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$ why do we let epsilon tend to zero from the right?

Tags: calculus, limits

I was taught that if we wish to integrate
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$$

then to avoid an undefined result the principal value ($\it{PV}$) of the integral needs to be taken:
$$PV\int_{-1}^{-1}\frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to \,0^+}\left[\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx\right]$$

But, when considering the graph of the function below:
[image: 1/x graph]
in the first integral $\epsilon$ must tend to zero from the left as it is in the negative (left) side of the graph. While, in the second integral, $\epsilon$ must tend to zero from the positive (right) side of the graph. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense.

So why are we not writing
$$PV\int_{-1}^{-1}\frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to \,0^-}\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx+\lim_{\epsilon \to \,0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$$ instead?

Comment: But $-ε$ is negative in the first integral!

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the edit

Comment: @Bernard Still don't understand, sorry, need more details.

Comment: The whole point of PV is that you are taking one limit so that the singularities might cancel. That won't happen if you are computing two separate limits. Also if $\epsilon$ is approaching 0 from the left and you are using $-\epsilon$ as a bound that's equivalent to taking the limit from the right.

Comment: @minimalrho Why is it "equivalent to taking the limit from the right"? I haven't come across the notation $0^+$ much before, that is why I'm having trouble understanding this

Comment: As @minimalrho said in his/her comment, –ε tends to $0$ from the left since ε approaches $0$ from the right.

Comment: See, what is the point. You have integral of form $\int_{-\infty}^{a}$, where as you are saying you need to write $\lim_{a \to 0-}$. But you have instead of $a$, $-\epsilon$. So you need $-\epsilon \to 0-$, which is the same as $\epsilon \to 0+$.

Comment: @Bernard Okay, so if I wrote $\epsilon$ in both the integrals (without the minus sign in the first) then what I wrote here $PV\int_{-1}^{-1}\frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to \,0^-}\int_{-1}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx+\lim_{\epsilon \to \,0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$ is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a good long look at
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to \,0^-}\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx
$$
You're taking the limit of integrals that go *past* the singularity (from $x = -1$ to some very small, positive number). Those integrals do not exist. As such, this limit is nonsense.

Even if you fix this, and take, say,
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to \,0^-}\int_{-1}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx+\lim_{\epsilon \to \,0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx
$$ instead, you have split it up into two limits. One limit tends to $-\infty$, and the other to $\infty$. None of those limits are numbers, and thus their sum is undefined.

I think it's better to leave the definition the way it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not trying to redefine anything here. I'm just trying to understand the accepted definition you mention. So it seems to me that the limit must be taken after the integration is carried out, is this correct?

Comment: @BLAZE Yup. Integrate both below and above the singularity, add the results, and take the limit of _that sum_, as you integrate closer and closer to the singularity.

Comment: Also why can we not write $PV\int_{-1}^{-1}\frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to \,0}\left[\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx\right]$? It is simply the $0^+$ notation that is bothering me here.

Comment: @BLAZE Without specifying that the upper integral is closing in on the singularity from _above_, and the lower integral is closing in _from below_, the term you're taking the limit of doesn't really make sense. Sure, you can define your notion of limit to be able to handle cases where some values of $\epsilon$ makes sense, and some don't, and in that case you _could_ write it like that. But this way they just avoid that problem entirely.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, up till just lately I have seen limits such as $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x+1}}{1-\sqrt{x+1}}$ but why are they not using  the $0^+$ or $0^-$ notation? The question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305497/calculating-the-following-limit-lim-x-to-0-frac-sqrtx21-sqrtx1?rq=1)

Comment: @BLAZE But in that case, there is no issue with $0^+$ or $0^-$ or $0$. The expression makes sense for both numbers below and numbers above $0$ (as long as they are close enough to $0$). So there is no need to worry about whether the limit is from above or below or both. And thus they revert to the default, which is two-sided.